# Cannot remove spotlight item from menu bar with `defaults`

Tags: spotlight, big-sur, preferences, plist, defaults

When unchecking "Show in Menu Bar" in System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Spotlight, it removes the `NSStatusItem Visible Item-0` from `com.apple.Spotlight.plist`. When enabling the setting, it sets this key to `true`.

It can be easily verified by using `defaults read com.apple.Spotlight` before and after unchecking the setting.

I'm trying to automate this in a macOS install script. The problem is that deleting the key with `defaults delete` or setting the value to `false` doesn't work. After doing `killall Spotlight; killall SystemUIServer` or rebooting the system, it sets back the value to `1`.

My guess was that some other files are modified when changing the setting with the GUI, so I tried this:

```sh
defaults read > before
# Manually change the setting in system preferences
defaults read > after
diff before > after
```

which outputs:

```
60c60
<         "_DKThrottledActivityLast_DKKnowledgeStorageLogging_DKKnowledgeStorageDidInsertEventsNotification:/app/usageActivityDate" = "2021-03-27 06:57:35 +0000";
---
>         "_DKThrottledActivityLast_DKKnowledgeStorageLogging_DKKnowledgeStorageDidInsertEventsNotification:/app/usageActivityDate" = "2021-03-27 06:57:49 +0000";
62c62
<         "_DKThrottledActivityLast_DKKnowledgeStorageLogging_DKKnowledgeStorageDidInsertLocalEventsNotification:/app/usageActivityDate" = "2021-03-27 06:57:35 +0000";
---
>         "_DKThrottledActivityLast_DKKnowledgeStorageLogging_DKKnowledgeStorageDidInsertLocalEventsNotification:/app/usageActivityDate" = "2021-03-27 06:57:49 +0000";
5357,5359c5357,5358
<         "NSStatusItem Visible Item-0" = 1;
<         SPMessageTracingWindowHideCount = 149;
<         SPMessageTracingWindowShowCount = 149;
---
>         SPMessageTracingWindowHideCount = 150;
>         SPMessageTracingWindowShowCount = 150;
5361c5360
<         "engagementCount-com.apple.Spotlight" = 87;
---
>         "engagementCount-com.apple.Spotlight" = 88;
9998c9997
<                 Age = "42540.278567375";
---
>                 Age = "42551.38625458333";
10050a10050
>                         352,
```

Maybe a file outside of the scope of `defaults` is modified?

Answer (score 2):

`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.Spotlight MenuItemHidden -int 1`

This works for me, and hides the spotlight icon immediately.
To turn it back on, it's just:

`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.Spotlight MenuItemHidden -int 0`